# StringBuilder output does not include character supplied in the constructor

Tags: java, stringbuilder

```
        StringBuilder bd = new StringBuilder('[');
        Iterator<String> iter = names.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            bd.append(iter.next());
            if (iter.hasNext()) {
                bd.append(", ");
            }
        }
        bd.append(']');
        return bd.toString();
```

I thought the output would come out looking something like `[<some stuff, if any>]`, but it looks like `<some stuff, if any>]` instead.

What is going on?

Comment: What does it look like?

Comment: You don't show any effort to investigate the problem on your own. This is a question that can be solved just by reading the API doc of the constructor you use. This would have taken ~30 sec. Therefore -1.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Change the char in the constructor args to a String.

```
StringBuilder bd = new StringBuilder("[");
```

Otherwise the char is being converted to an int [to define initial capacity](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#StringBuilder(int)).

Comment: Oooooooh, d'oh! That's stupid of me! (But seriously, that is SO NOT intuitive).